# Получить почту профиля Twitter

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-api

Вот разрешения в самой панели приложений Twitter:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код которым пытаюсь вытащить email:

```
twitterAuthClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(Result<String> result) {
                            Log.d("wtf", " email = " + result.toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                            Log.d("wtf", " email = " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
```

Проходит вроде все гладко, подтверждаю авторизацию, появляется запрос для разрешения предоставить почту, но в ответ получаю - Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address.

Много перерыл информации, ответа не нашел. 
Спасибо за внимание!